# Override config

Tags: magento2

I am trying to override the config in a early stage.

I have created a option where the admin can choose in the config section from which website they want to inherit the config from. I am stuck on loading the config for that defined website.

Snippet:

```
<?php
namespace Virdock\ShareConfig\Plugin\Magento\Framework\App\Config;

class Data
{
    public $storeManager;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager)
    {
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    public function aroundGetValue(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\Data $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        $path = null
    ){
        // No path or the path is the shareconfig path.
        // Or we dont have a inherit set.
        // Than let the original method handle it.
        if ($path === null
            || \Virdock\ShareConfig\Model\Share::SHARECONFIG_XPATH === $path
            || ! $inherit = $proceed(\Virdock\ShareConfig\Model\Share::SHARECONFIG_XPATH)
        ){
            return $proceed($path);
        }

        $inherited = $this->storeManager->getWebsite($inherit)->getConfig($path);

        return $inherited;
    }
}
```

So in the above snippet the part missing / not working correct is the `$inherited` variable. The `getConfig()` returns a false when a value is not defined. So what i would actually want is to get the whole config tree just as it is in `\Magento\Framework\App\Config\Data` for a specific scope / scope id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the entire config tree try passing in an empty string for the path.

```
$configTree = $this->storeManager->getWebsite($inherit)->getConfig('');
```

The `Website::getConfig` method is using `Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface` to gather the config data, and you can do the same if you have more dynamic scope type and scope code combinations in your code.